# Embed PDF in IFrame (same domain) and control height (scrollbars)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

**What I am attempting to achieve:**
I have a page that has some header information followed by a document via embedded PDF and finally some footer information. Ideally, this would be displayed as one continuous document that could be printed as such.

**What I have found:**
I load the PDF into an iframe on the page. Because this document is not public it is requested via server-side action that checks permissions and returns the document as Content-Type: application/pdf;

This works to load the PDF but I am unable to turn off toolbars and other embedded PDF viewer controls (minor issue)

When I attempt to read the iframe document height using javascript in the containing page to modify the iframe height and thus remove the scrollbars I get a cross-domain origin issue despite the PDF loading from the same domain, server, etc.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, but all of the resources are on the same domain. I wonder if it is an issue of the integrated PDF viewer control (I'm using firefox for testing)

Answer (score 0):

There is a standalone viewer which you can use show pdfs:

```html
 <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This don't provide you with

> toolbars and other embedded PDF viewer controls

**EDIT :**  If you don't want to use the above option then you can also use [PDF.js](https://pdfjs.express/blog/how-embed-pdf-in-html-website) an open project to render pdf in html.

```html
<iframe id="pdf-js-viewer" src="/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fmy-pdf-file.pdf" title="webviewer" frameborder="0" width="500" height="600"></iframe>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative

Comment: This google docs viewer is unlikely to work as the PDF file is only available to a user with a logged in session on the server.

Comment: then you can use pdf-js